# C++ Casting Pointer Arrays (without dataloss or overuse of memory)

Tags: c++, arrays, casting

Say for example that I have a class, that stores a very large array of some datatype (__type) as a pointer. However, I wish to initialize an object of this class using a different type. The code I have can be condensed to below:

```
template <typename __type> class MyStorageClass {
private: 
    __type* _data;
public:
    template <typename __alt> MyStorageClass(int size, __alt* data) { // some init function }
    extern friend print() const; // print to the screen
}
```

This works fine if I make an object of `MyStorageClass<int>` and initialize it to `(new int[2] { 1, 2 })`. However, the problem occours if I try to initialize it as: `(new float[2] { 1, 2 })`, even though the size of `int` and `float` are the same (so in theory they will cast to each other).

1. If I initialize it by: `_data = (__type*) data;`, the elements get changed.

   ```
   MyStorageClass<int> msc1(2, new float[2] { 1, 2 });
   msc1.print();
   ```

   Yields: `msc1=[1065353216, 1073741824]`, not `msc1=[1, 2]`
2. If I initialize it through a for loop:

   ```
   // some init function
   _data = new __type[size];
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) _data[i] = data[i];
   ```

   This works, and properly defines the object. However, It creates a new array in memory (at `&_data`) of the same size as `sizeof(data)`, rather than use the already allocated memory at `&data`, which is unnecessarily memory intensive and can be confusing to the user.

QUESTION: Is there a way to cast an array (from `float*` to `int*` or another data type) using the same memory address?

UPDATE: Try with unions failed.

```
union FloatIntUnion{
    float _f;
    int _i;
    FloatIntUnion(int i) { _i = i; }
    FloatIntUnion(float f) { _f = f; }
    operator float() { return _f; }
    operator int() { return _i; }
    operator std::string() const { std::stringstream oss; oss << _f; return oss.str(); }
};

MyStorageClass<int> msc2(2, new FloatIntUnion[2]{ float(1), float(2) });
msc2.print();
```

Yields: `msc1=[1065353216, 1073741824]`

Comment: You cannot do this.

Comment: Identifiers containing double underscore `__` are reserved.

Comment: If all you were casting was the float, the value would be converted to an integer value. Casting pointers this way violates the aliasing rules, so technically anything could happen. What is most likely is the ints will take the radically different storage format of a float and try to use it as an into with no conversion whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if `int(1)` and `float(1)` has the same value, the bit patterns stored in memory are *totally* different.

When you do `(int*) data;` **you** tell the compiler that the bit patterns are the same, but as you see when you print them, they are not.

So this is not going to work.

In the loop in option 2), the assignment `_data[i] = data[i];` doesn't just copy 4 bytes, it also transforms the bit patterns from `float` to `int`.

Comment: Better answer than the dupe I was going to use in a close vote.

Comment: Thanks, I didn;t think that the bit-paterns where different, but thinking about it makes sence.

Comment: So in theory if I where using different types, (say MyType1, and MyType2), with the same bit patterns, this could work?

Comment: Not really, no. If you were to cast from `int` to `long` you might not *notice* any problems, by there is still the aliasing rules hinted at in the comments. To access an `int` you must really *have* an `int` in your program, not just `float`s  or `long`s.